# Invoke keypress event in android?

Tags: android, keypress

I need to invoke a key press event in android .
Any suggestions ?????

Comment: Try http://google.com/search?q=Invoke+keypress+event+in+android. The third result looks just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the instrumentation class :

```
Instrumentation i = new Instrumentation();
i.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
```

This should be equivalent to a A pressed on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the response will be testing it soon.
Hope it will do the job.
  Thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget that this method is synchronous, so you might also need to wrap it in something asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

The following example shows how to invoke Key Back key event:

```
KeyEvent eventDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
KeyEvent eventUp = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
dispatchKeyEvent(eventDown);
dispatchKeyEvent(eventUp);
```