# Android Development: Keypress/keyEvent

Tags: android

Im developing an application and got stuck. i have a normal simple Button. What i want to do is that if i click this button it will behave just like you press the SPACE on the soft keyboard.

How do i do this. there must be a way because you can develop a softkeyboard.

So repeat xP How do i "inject" a keypress or simulate a keypress if i press a button.

Thank you!
//Me

Comment: well thankyou. any idea of the topic thought?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361281/invoke-keypress-event-in-android/3361344#3361344

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText e = new EditText(context);
Button b = new Button(context);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        e.setText(e.getText().toString() + " ");
    }
});
```

click the button, append a space character to the `EditText`'s value

this should be valid code, but i have not tested it

Comment: this wont work for webview. i want to simulate keypress just like softkeyboard not add text, ok?