# Is it possible to make a call from code, and then send keypress events to the dialler?

Tags: android, keypress, phone-call

OK I want to be able test internal phone systems in an automated fashion using an Android app, the requirements are asking for an app which can initiate a call programatically. If this is possible then when the call starts they wish to be able to send key presses, like imagine the phone menu says "press 5 to get to the X menu".. can we send that keypress from code? This way the whole system could be tested with a series of waits, and keypresses sent to the dialler.

I'm not sure how to find out if this is actually possible.. I saw PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, but I havent been able to find any resources or examples on doing this, does anyone have any information? I actually got in touch with a freelancer who ended up saying it was definitely not possible (he's pretty good and he simply said 'pressing dialpad during call was impossible'), but my client is telling me apps already exist to do this, so any tips would be helpful!..

Comment: for the first part see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make a call from code. See:

[How to make a phone call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically)

You can invoke key presses from code as well:

[Invoke keypress event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361281/invoke-keypress-event-in-android?rq=1)

As for doing it during a call, I haven't tried this, But you can try it using the methods from the links. Good luck!